# Initializing Object in XAML File breakes Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object

I'm trying to create an object in my xaml file like this:

```
xmnls:pfvm="clr-namespace:GameOfLifeMVVM.ViewModel"
```

Well the i go in the `<Window.Resources>` and try to create the PlayfieldViewModel obejct like this:

```
<pfvm:PlayfieldViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
```

And after this line the Designer is crashing and can't load the UI. The Error is: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException.

I need this, because I want to bind a Button Command to a `ICommand` attribute in my `PlayfieldViewModel` Class.

**The PlayfieldViewModel constructor:**

```
public PlayFieldViewModel()
{
   objCommand = new ButtonCommand(this);
}
```

**My Folder structure:**

```
GameOfLiveMVVM
-View
--MainWindow.xaml
-ViewModel
--PlayfieldViewModel.cs
```

Comment: A bit more code would be helpful. Also, does `PlayfieldViewModel` have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Also, if you are using `PlayfieldViewModel` as the DataContext, then it should be inside `<Window.DataContext>` rather than `<Window.Resources>`.

Comment: And in order to avoid that it breaks the XAML Designer, you may perhaps assign the DataContext in a try/catch block in the MainWindow constructor like `DataContext = new PlayfieldViewModel();`

Comment: Well i'm trying to build it like on [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) this page under Level 2 the first thing you will see.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: I will do it give me some minutes

Comment: For the sake of testing try `objCommand = new ButtonCommand(null);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i just found my fault:

In the Constructor of PlayfieldViewModel i made a `new ButtonCommand(this)`.

The problem was, that in my ButtonCommand class i had an object of my PlayfieldViewModel class like this:

```
private PlayfieldViewModel pf = new PlayfieldViewModel();
```

And in the constructor of my `ButtonCommand` class i set the `pf` to the parameter of the constructor like this:

```
public ButtonCommand(PlayfieldViewModel para)
{
   pf = para;
}
```

And this step could not be done because the `pf` has already been filled with an other object when i declared it with `new`.

Maybe this helps someone!

Thank you to @Scroog1 for pushing me to make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example!